# How to count number of users accessed my Ruby on Rails Application hosted on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Ruby on Rails application hosted in an ECS cluster on AWS.

how to find how many users accessed my ruby on rails application in a day??

I have 5 different Ruby on Rails modules running as 5 different containers in AWS ECS Cluster, If I could know number of requests coming for each module a day, based on that report I can scale my containers.

(I use Cloudwatch to store all application logs in AWS , If we can get any information about number of hits for a module in a day, I can create a dashboard in Cloudwatch, what logs i can monitor to get this info)

(I also use AWS Application load balancer aswell infront of the ruby on rails application)

Please help me in finding number of users accesing my module or no.of hits per module in a day.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use some analytics, for example [Andrew Kane's gem Ahoy](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy)